# Sockets in *.plist

Tags: applications, filesystem, launchd, plist

My app needs to create a system-wide socket (unique independently of the number of users on the Mac).  I'm using a *.plist to this end:

```
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
    <key>Listener</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SockPathMode</key>
        <integer>438</integer><!-- 0666 -->
        <key>SockPathName</key>
        <string>/var/tmp/myApp.socket</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I had recently a bug report which was quite painful to debug, and eventually it appeared that the failure was due to the user not having a `/var/tmp` directory.  So my questions are:

- what can I do to get more meaningful error messages when the Socket cannot be created?
- what can I do to get the directory created if it does not exist?
- is `/var/tmp` the right place for such sockets?  Should I go for `/tmp` instead?   Or some other directory?

### EDIT

FWIW, I just noticed that in `/var/run` there seems to be quite a few sockets, some sufficiently important so that I may consider the Mac won't be usable if the directory were to be missing.

```
$ ls -l /var/run
total 88
-rw-------  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 automount.initialized
drwxr-xr-x  3 _assetcache      _assetcache        96 19 jan 15:26 com.apple.AssetCache
----------  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 com.apple.WindowServer.didRunThisBoot
-rw-------  1 root             daemon              4 22 jan 11:14 com.apple.dt.instruments.servicehub_63755_505.pid
-r--------  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 com.apple.loginwindow.didRunThisBoot
-r--------  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 com.apple.mdmclient.daemon.didRunThisBoot
-rw-------  1 root             daemon              0 20 jan 12:16 com.apple.parentalcontrols.webfilterctl.mutex
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon              0 20 jan 11:48 com.apple.softwareupdate.availableupdatesupdated
drwxr-xr-x  3 root             daemon             96 19 jan 15:29 com.apple.xpc.smd
srwxrwxrwx  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 cupsd
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon              3 19 jan 15:24 diskarbitrationd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  3 _displaypolicyd  _displaypolicyd    96 19 jan 15:24 displaypolicyd
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root             daemon             57 22 jan 11:44 docker.sock -> /Users/akim/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/s60
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon             16 19 jan 15:24 fudinit
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon              6 21 jan 13:20 hdiejectd.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon              3 19 jan 15:24 kdc.pid
srw-rw-rw-  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 mDNSResponder
drwx------  3 root             daemon             96 21 jan 13:21 mds
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon              3 19 jan 15:24 mds.pid
srwxrwxrwx  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 portmap.socket
srwxrwxrwx  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 pppconfd
drwxr-xr-x  4 root             daemon            128 19 jan 15:24 racoon
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon              4 19 jan 15:24 racoon.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root             daemon            379 22 jan 13:30 resolv.conf
srw-rw-rw-  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 syslog
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root             daemon              3 19 jan 15:24 syslog.pid
-r--r--r--  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 systemkeychaincheck.done
srw-rw-rw-  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 systemkeychaincheck.socket
srwxrwxrwx  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 usbmuxd
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root             daemon           5652 22 jan 11:44 utmpx
srw-------  1 root             daemon              0 19 jan 15:24 vpncontrol.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root             wheel               0 19 jan 15:24 wifi
```

Comment: This question is better suited to StackOverflow. `/var/tmp/` has historically been Apple's recommended location for domain sockets on macOS. Have you investigated XPC services? These are often recommended by Apple engineers for interprocess communication.

Comment: Hi!  No, I've not looked at XPC services, I will. By "has historically been" do mean that before `/var/tmp` was and now `/var/run` is?  I don't seem to have enough reputation to _move_ the question, are you suggesting I should open a new one on SO?

Comment: You should ask again on StackOverflow – you will attract better answers from developers. This site focuses on users. I say historically because Apple have removed the sample code that used domain sockets in favour of XPC based implementations. `/var/tmp` is suitable for third party processes.

Comment: `/var/tmp` is owned by `root` so an installation without it seems to be a fringe case.

Comment: Repeated on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387834/macos-sockets-in-plist.